# How to rotate background Image with css and with fading effect?

Tags: jquery, css

Below solution works for me, but I need to add continuous rotation of the background images and a fading effect.

```
var bg = ['img3', 'img1', 'img2'];
$.each(bg, function(index, ui) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').removeAttr('class').addClass(ui);
    }, 2000 * index)
});
```

Can any one help with this?

Comment: this may help u http://jsfiddle.net/jSvUE/

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Cycle Plugin is a slideshow plugin that supports many different types of transition effects.It is also very good image rotating .you can use that

[See this for more information and demo - JQuery cycle plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)

[Live demo given by Cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/basic.html)

Comment: @Ann Hope you will try by yourself. you can take reference from source page of given demo link.

Comment: Thank you for quick answers. I get it working using this: http://dhirajkumarsingh.wordpress.com/2013/05/05/jquery-animate-full-page-multiple-background-image-fade-in-out-effect/

Answer (score 0):

Eventually used a different sliding image.
http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/basic.html